# Solr: missing content stream, Magento: error while reindexing

Tags: java, magento, solr

This one is driving me nuts.

The problem occurs in a two-server-system, where server A runs Magento EE 1.11 and server B runs Solr 3.4.0. Both servers are within the same network (192.168.x.x) and the Magento backend on A is configured to use the Solr daemon on B for catalog searches.

Imo, the Magento backend is configured correctly, as Magentos `Test Connection` feature always returns `Successful! Test again?` and I can find the pings caused by the tests in the Solr logs.

But when trying to

```
System -> Index Management -> Catalog Search Index -> Reindex data
```

Magento always fails with "There was a problem with reindexing process".

Checking the Solr logs gives **missing content stream** and returns HTTP 400 (bad request):

```
Nov 10, 2011 3:50:16 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/admin/ping params={} hits=0 status=0 QTime=1
Nov 10, 2011 3:50:16 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/admin/ping params={} status=0 QTime=2
Nov 10, 2011 3:50:16 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/admin/ping params={} hits=0 status=0 QTime=1
Nov 10, 2011 3:50:16 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/admin/ping params={} status=0 QTime=2
Nov 10, 2011 3:50:16 PM org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor finish
INFO: {} 0 0
Nov 10, 2011 3:50:16 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: missing content stream
        at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:62)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1368)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:356)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:252)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:945)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

Nov 10, 2011 3:50:16 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=json&<delete fromPending="true"+fromCommitted%3D"true"><query>store_id:2</query></delete>} status=400 QTime=0
Nov 10, 2011 3:50:16 PM org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor finish
INFO: {} 0 0
Nov 10, 2011 3:50:16 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: missing content stream
        at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:62)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1368)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:356)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:252)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:945)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

Nov 10, 2011 3:50:16 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/update params={<rollback/>=&wt=json} status=400 QTime=0
```

The only thing that somehow looks strange to me in this error trace is, that in the params of the  `/update` command only *one* of the `=` is url-encoded to `%3D`, but all others are *not*.

```
<delete fromPending="true"+fromCommitted%3D"true"><query>store_id:2</query></delete>
```

Otoh I'm quite new to Solr and have no idea whether this is just maybe a bug of the Java logger itself.

I also have checked `Apache_Solr_Service::deleteByQuery()`, the PHP method which is producing the failing Solr query, but couldn't find any bugs in there so far.

The production environment unfortunately is bound to PHP 5.2.16 in this case, so another thing coming to my mind was possible problems with `htmlspecialchars`, `stream_context_set_option` or `file_get_contents` under PHP 5.2.16, but IIRC there weren't such.

So my question is: **What is causing the 'missing content stream' error and/or how to fix this?**

Comment: @zuloo: I was about to upvote your cURL suggestion, but you seem to have deleted your answer quite recently. What happened?^^

Comment: I was just wondering if you did notice it - and was not sure that it might work, as I did not have such problems but worked in an environment where `file_gets_content()` is disabled for security reasons - just thought it might work - I undeleted it, after checking it again...

Comment: And I was not able to answer your question in detail, which made me think my answer might be just crap or irrelevant

Comment: @zuloo: no worries, it wasn't crap. It might not explain the reason or provide a fix for the cause, but at least you provided a functional workaround. Which imo always is better than nothing^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a known bug in early PHP releases with releases built with "--with-curl-wrappers".

By any chance did you compile with curl wrappers? Try re-compiling without and see how you fare.

Comment: Checked. The problem server in fact was compiled `-with-curl-wrappers`. But I cannot see how adding cURL context options - which is what afaik `-with-curl-wrappers` does in the end - should affect PHPs core stream handling in a way. I mean, the problem occurs when *no* cURL methods are being used at all. Just `stream_content_set_option()` and `file_get_contents()`. Mind to explain why you think -with-curl-wrappers could be the problem here?

Comment: I've come across the issue before a few times, and re-compiling without curl wrappers always fixes the issue.

As to how I found out, that was a guessing game and comparison of a bunch of different servers and configs we have set up.

Comment: I did a recompile on another machine w/o `--with-curl-wrappers`. The other machine isn't exactly a copy of the problem server (OS and Apache version slightly differ, PHP is the same 5.2.16), but I can confirm, there's no Magento reindex issues using this compilation. I still don't know, *why* and *how* dropping cURL wrappers could affect PHP core stream handling, but I'll take that as a fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

we rewrote the enterprise/search/client/solr.php to use curl.

you would have to alter the _sendRawGet and _sendRawPost Methods:

```
protected function _sendRawGet($url, $timeout = FALSE)
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    if($timeout && is_numeric($timeout))
    {
        curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, floatval($timeout));
    }else{
        curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, floatval(5));
    }
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($this->getUserLogin() . ':' . $this->getPassword())));
    $ret = curl_exec($curl);
    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
    if(curl_errno($curl))
    {
        throw new Exception('"' . curl_errno($curl) . '" Info: ' . print_r($info,true));
    }
    $header = substr($ret, 0, $info['header_size']);
    $body = substr($ret, -$info['download_content_length']);
    $response = new Apache_Solr_Response($body, explode("\r\n",$header), $this->_createDocuments, $this->_collapseSingleValueArrays);
    if ($response->getHttpStatus() != 200 && $response->getHttpStatus() != 100)
    {
        throw new Exception('"' . $response->getHttpStatus() . '" Status: ' . $response->getHttpStatusMessage(), $response->getHttpStatus());
    }
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response;
}


protected function _sendRawPost($url, $rawPost, $timeout = FALSE, $contentType = 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8')
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    if($timeout && is_numeric($timeout))
    {
        curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, floatval($timeout));
    }else{
        curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, floatval(5));
    }
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    $sendHeader = array(
        "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($this->getUserLogin() . ':' . $this->getPassword()),
        "Content-Type: ".$contentType
    );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $rawPost);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $sendHeader);
    $ret = curl_exec($curl);
    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
    if(curl_errno($curl))
    {
         throw new Exception('"' . curl_errno($curl) . '" Info: ' . print_r($info,true));
    }
    $header = substr($ret, 0, $info['header_size']);
    $body = substr($ret, -$info['download_content_length']);
    $response = new Apache_Solr_Response($body, explode("\r\n",$header), $this->_createDocuments, $this->_collapseSingleValueArrays);
    if ($response->getHttpStatus() != 200 && $response->getHttpStatus() != 100)
    {
        throw new Exception('"' . $response->getHttpStatus() . '" Status: ' . $response->getHttpStatusMessage(), $response->getHttpStatus());
    }
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response;
}
```

maybe this works, we didn't get any problems using this method

Answer (score 0):

Magento EE 1.11.0.0 uses combos of `stream_content_set_option()` and `file_get_contents()` calls to build and execute the Solr requests, so the problem seems to be related to the **stream handling** of PHP 5.2.16<sup>*</sup>.

As I was running out of time, I've just overridden the `Apache_Solr_Service` class and modified the methods `_sendRawGet()` and `_sendRawPost()` to use [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) requests instead of PHP streams.

This workaround works perfectly fine so far (btw: thanks to @zuloo. I had the same thought to use cURL to workaround, but only wanted to use it as a last resort).

I'm still wondering what is causing this error when using PHP streams (meanwhile my prime suspect is chunked transfer encoding). Maybe someone else drops by and can shed some light, so I'm going to let the question stay unsolved for now.

---

<sub>* which is somewhat strange, because according to the [Magento EE specs](http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements) only PHP 5.2.13+ should berequired.</sub>